# Laravel How to count does not have items in many to many relationships

Tags: php, laravel

i have posts table and tags table i keep them in posts_tags table so these boths are many to many. I want to list tags with count which posts they are not include.

For example;

tree ( 63 posts does not have this tag) forest ( 50 posts does not have this tag)

How can i do this list?

Comment: You can try this
`$tags = Tags::doesntHave('posts')->get();`

Comment: Or you can try this too
`$tags = Tags::whereDoesntHave('posts', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('tags', 'like', 'tagname%');
})->get();`

Comment: Here you can watch it in details
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence